# Why am I getting timezone differences when converting date and getting current date?

Tags: ios, swift, date, dateformatter

In the following code example:

```
func numberOfDaysBetween(toDate: String) -> Int { // toDate = "2021/12/21"

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
    
    let currentDate = Date()
    let toDateFormatted = dateFormatter.date(from: toDate)
    
    print ("Current Date:     \(currentDate)")         // Current Date:     2021-12-21 11:50:12 +0000
    print ("ToDate:           \(toDate)")              // ToDate:           2021/12/21
    print ("ToDateFormatted:  \(toDateFormatted)")     // ToDateFormatted:  Optional(2021-12-20 13:30:00 +0000)
    print (dateFormatter.timeZone)                     // Optional(Australia/Adelaide (fixed (equal to current)))
    
    return 1 // Test value
}
```

I am not seeing correct dates.  I have spent 4 hours trying various options, but keep coming back to the same output.  How do I see the expected output below?

I am expecting to see the following:

```
    print ("Current Date:     \(currentDate)")         // Current Date:     2021-12-21
    print ("ToDate:           \(toDate)")              // ToDate:           2021/12/21
    print ("ToDateFormatted:  \(toDateFormatted)")     // ToDateFormatted:  2021/12/21
    print (dateFormatter.timeZone)                     // Optional(Australia/Adelaide (fixed (equal to current)))
```

Interestingly, I am located in Adelaide, and the time is 22:20 (10:20 PM).  Why is the time different when calling Date()?

Comment: "I am not seeing correct dates" Yes you are. "I am expecting to see the following" Why would you expect that? For instance take `currentDate`. You never format it so why on earth would you expect it to come out as `2021-12-21`? If you want a date to appear in a certain string format, format it! You did _make_ a date formatter, but you are not _using_ it on any of your dates!

Comment: Why am I being voted down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 func numberOfDaysBetween(toDate: String) -> Int { // toDate = "2021/12/21"

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
    
    let currentDate = Date()
    let toDateFormatted = dateFormatter.date(from: toDate)
    let df = dateFormatter.string(from: toDateFormatted!)
    
    print ("Current Date:     \(currentDate)")         // Current Date:     2021-12-21 11:50:12 +0000
    print ("ToDate:           \(toDate)")              // ToDate:           2021/12/21
    print ("ToDateFormatted:  \(df)")     // ToDateFormatted:  Optional(2021-12-20 13:30:00 +0000)
    print (dateFormatter.timeZone)                     // Optional(Australia/Adelaide (fixed (equal to current)))
    
    return 1 // Test value
}
```

try this . you were trying to convert the string to date. so that you got that format, you supposed to change it required string format.